# External + Internal wifi card inconsistent device names

Tags: networking, wireless

When I turn on laptop without external card connected internal has dev name wlan0, then I connect external wifi-card it becames wlan1 and I like it.

But if I will start laptop with external card connected it will be wlan0 and internal became wlan1.

The problem is that I want to have power safe mode always off for external card so I need to run a command on startup like:

```
iw dev wlan1 set power_save off
```

But device name inconsistent, is there're a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be running an older version of Ubuntu (pre 16.04) that does not enable Predictable Network Interface Names by default.

In order to use it you need to opt in by passing `net.ifnames=1` on the kernel command line.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: thx, I'm using refind so it won't work with GRUB, but found following solution reading an article u have sent: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/07/msg01453.html